# If two sets $A,B$ are (topologically) separated, is $m^*(A\cup B)=m^*(A)+m^*(B)$ always true?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

By separated, we mean $\overline{A}\cap B=\emptyset$ and $\overline{B}\cap A=\emptyset$.
If $dist(A,B)>0$, then we know that $m^*(A\cup B)=m^*(A)+m^*(B)$. If $A\cap B=\emptyset$, we know that there is a counterexample here.

BTW, the outter meausre $m^*$ here is the one for Lebesgue measure.

Comment: In a metric space, if $A$ and $B$ are separated, then there are open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $A\subseteq U$, $B\subseteq V$, and $U\cap V=\emptyset$. Maybe that could be useful?

Comment: @bof. Excellent hint.

Comment: @bof Yeah, I know how to do it